# Get java.util.Date out from Joda-Time DateTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I have code like this:

```
// old_api(Date date)
old_api(calendar.getTime());
```

Currently, I need to replace `Calendar` with Joda-Time `DateTime`. I was wondering how I can get `java.util.Date` out from Joda-Time `DateTime`?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use [`DateTime#toDate()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate%28%29).

```
Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Comment: This looks like it has both date & time.

Comment: @tamersalama: the question asks clearly how to get a `java.util.Date`, not how to get only day/month/year.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is: Extract milli-seconds from joda-datetime instance and then pass it to java.util.Date constructor.

```
Date date = new java.util.Date(jodaDateTime.getMillis())
```